# How to use Ant plugin on Jenkins to compile a source to a .jar

Tags: java, git, ant, jar, jenkins

I've been trying to compile the source that comes in from my git to a .jar with the Ant Plugin. But I don't know how to make a build.xml or set it up... Could anyone give me an example of a build.xml so it can compile the source in the workspace and then have the .jar be the job main file. If you have any questions please ask :)

Comment: is there a pom or gradle file? it would be better to not recreate the build.

Comment: No, sir. There isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Example of an Ant build.xml file

http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

Comment: Where would I put this and what would I put in the build.xml?